# PHP Splitting up values returned from a function

Tags: php

I have this function I am calling in a class. It gets all the phone numbers assigned to a user or company.

```
foreach($obj as $file) {
$clean_number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$file['matchrule']);
$clean_number = substr($clean_number, 1);
echo $clean_number;
}
```

It returns all the values and I see them in this function calling the function above:

```
$get_numbers_from_domain = $api->_get_numbers($domain);
echo $get_numbers_from_domain;
```

So the question is, how do I split the values and treat each phone number returned as separate so that I can input them into another function instead of having a long run on of numbers?

The returned value string looks like this: (minus the x's)

> 8004xxx3048138xxx436

What I have been trying was something like this with no success by adding a "." at the end of my returned numbers.

```
$NumArray = explode('.', $get_numbers_from_domain);
foreach($NumArray as $num_Array){
    echo $num_Array.'<br>';  
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code of the function? What you have shown only echoes something out, it does not return anything.

Comment: Put the values into an array and return the array.

Comment: Could you share the string that you get in the `$clean_number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$clean_number=array();
foreach($obj as $file) {
$clean_number = preg_replace('/[^0- 9]/','',$file['matchrule']);
$clean_number[]= substr($clean_number, 1);
}
return $clean_number;
```

So it return the numbers as an array

Comment: Hey, do I need to do anything on the otherside so it shows more than just "Array"?

Comment: $get_numbers_from_domain = $api- >_get_numbers($domain);
   print_r($get_numbers_from_domain);  if you want to display the array or as you want

Comment: Playing with the code now. Not sure why the array values come out blank.